# How can i connect to the server and run a command to run a batch file from within the server?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is the .bat file I am currently working on:

```
@echo off

net use \\servername\ /user:admin admin
call "C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\RBDPAY.bat"

exit
```

However when running the .bat file from local machine it give me this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

SysInternals has a tool called [psExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) that does just that.

> PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute
>   processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for
>   console applications, without having to manually install client
>   software. PsExec's most powerful uses include launching interactive
>   command-prompts on remote systems and remote-enabling tools like
>   IpConfig that otherwise do not have the ability to show information
>   about remote systems.

Your example would look like this:

```
psexec \\servername"C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\RBDPAY.bat"
```